# Linq Projection being cached incorrectly in NHibernate 3.2

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

Given a simple projection like the following, NHibernate will cache the query plan and not update the value of the variable when the query is the same:

```
    int argValue = 1;
    var result1 = database.Users.Select(x => new {x.Name, BadArg = argValue}).First();

    argValue = 2;
    var result2 = database.Users.Select(x => new {x.Name, BadArg = argValue}).First();
```

**Expected**

result1 value would be Name = "Bob" and BadArg = 1

result2 value would be Name = "Bob" and BadArg = 2

**Actual**

result1 value would be Name = "Bob" and BadArg = 1

result2 value would be Name = "Bob" and **BadArg = 1**

Obviously this can cause lots of crazy behavior if you aren't expecting it.  I've seen a [couple bug reports](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2500?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs) similar to this in NHibernate's bug tracking, but there hasn't been any action on it since last May.  So either nobody is using Linq to Nhibernate very much or there is some workaround that I don't know about.

Before I dig into NHibernate source, is there a way to disable the query plan caching to prevent this behavior or some other workaround or has anyone applied the patch from the above link?

**Note**

The example is meant to keep the question simple, in reality I have a complicated projection that I want to keep as an IQueryable, prematurely converting to an IEnumerable won't work.

**Update**
Doesn't work in github master for Nhibernate 3.2.1

Comment: I've been looking into this out of curiosity, and it looks like the issue isn't NHibernate's cache proper, it's the Linq expression tree cache. The problem is, the expression tree gets simplified, and the variable reference reduced to a constant expression, after which the cache key gets constructed -- but by that time there's no telling the difference between a scope variable ref and a constant. :-/

Comment: I've been having this problem too, and it's such a time waster.  Every few months it crops back up, and I've forgotten about it, only to rediscover it again.  In my case I'm not projecting to anonymous objects, but to value objects of my own creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid caching entirely, try changing your code to this:

```
int argValue = 1;
var result1 = database.Users.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {x.Name, BadArg = argValue}).First();

argValue = 2;
var result2 = database.Users.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new {x.Name, BadArg = argValue}).First();
```

What happens is that instead of using the NHLinq Select method, you'll end up using the System.Linq Select method -- effectively preventing NHibernate from caching the projection. Of course, the downside is that you'll do the projection in memory, so you'll end up selecting all the fields from your users table instead of just the ones you want.

Comment: I'm aware that will work but sort of defeats the purpose a bit.  My example was kept simple to for the question, but in reality I want to keep it as an IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to disable the first level cache:
http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/10/08/statelesssession-nhibernate-without-first-level-cache/

I don't think you can disable the second-level cache but I think you don't have to for this problem.

(Essentially you'll need to create and destroy sessions for each query.)

If you find the problem is still persistent though, you'll have to do what Rytmis suggested.

Comment: Creating a different session just to execute a query seems a bit heavy handed and could have bad consequences with objects from another session.

Comment: Depends on what you're projecting -- if your projection only contains scalar values, it shouldn't be a problem. But you're right, it doesn't feel right.